# How to setup Access-Control-Allow-Origin filter problematically in Spring Security 3.2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, http-headers, servlet-filters

I am trying to setup my Spring server with Spring Security 3.2 to be able to do an ajax login request.

I followed the [Spring Security 3.2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qoR6lY6biO4) video and couple of posts but the issue is that I am getting

```
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

For the login requests (see below).

I have created a CORSFilter setup and I can access the unprotected resources in my system with the appropriate headers being added to the response.

My guess is that I am not adding the `CORSFilter` to security filter chain or it may be too late far in the chain. Any idea will be appreciated.

**WebAppInitializer**

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        WebApplicationContext rootContext = createRootContext(servletContext);

        configureSpringMvc(servletContext, rootContext);

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic corsFilter = servletContext.addFilter("corsFilter", CORSFilter.class);
        corsFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }

    private WebApplicationContext createRootContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        rootContext.register(SecurityConfig.class, PersistenceConfig.class, CoreConfig.class);

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
        servletContext.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true");

        return rootContext;
    }


    private void configureSpringMvc(ServletContext servletContext, WebApplicationContext rootContext) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext mvcContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        mvcContext.register(MVCConfig.class);

        mvcContext.setParent(rootContext);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet = servletContext.addServlet(
                "webservice", new DispatcherServlet(mvcContext));
        appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        Set<String> mappingConflicts = appServlet.addMapping("/api/*");

        if (!mappingConflicts.isEmpty()) {
            for (String s : mappingConflicts) {
                LOG.error("Mapping conflict: " + s);
            }
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "'webservice' cannot be mapped to '/'");
        }
    }
```

**SecurityWebAppInitializer:**

```
public class SecurityWebAppInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

**SecurityConfig:**

Requests to */api/users* - work well and the Access-Control-Allow headers are added .
I disabled csrf and headers just to make sure this is not the case

```
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
    protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .headers().disable()                
            .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/users/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
```

**CORFilter:**

```
@Component
public class CORSFilter implements Filter{
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CORSFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void destroy() {}
}
```

**Login Request:**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/devstage-1.0/login
Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:9000
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:9000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
username:user
password:password
```

Comment: Can you add your Spring security config?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All I was missing was [AddFilterBefore](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RC2/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#addFilterBefore%28javax.servlet.Filter,%20java.lang.Class%29) when configuring the security configuration.

So the final version was:

```
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
  }


  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
          .addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)

          .formLogin()
              .loginPage("/login")
              .and()
          .authorizeRequests()
              .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

And remove the CORSFilter from `WebAppInitializer`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit too late to answer your question but thought might be worth to share. In your initial configuration you had registered the Spring Security initializer configuration metadata with the root context:

```
rootContext.register(SecurityConfig.class, PersistenceConfig.class, CoreConfig.class);
```

When you can do this, you don't need to as it will couple the security filter chain with the web application context which is not required. Instead, you could just add the filter chain in the plain old way by registering the DelegatingFilterProxy as a filter. Of course, you'll need to maintain the order by adding the Cors Filter before adding the spring security filter chain.

This way, you'll be able to use the stock CorsFilter (just by adding init params) that comes with the org.apache.catalina.filters package. Anyways, you can stick with your own configuration too! :)

Comment: Hey, I'm interested in this. I'm in trouble with a vendor application, and i need to add cors filter. Could you guide me a little. What do you mean by: (just by adding init params) . I want to use the provided cors-filter of tomcat as you meantion. Could you please provide me with the steps ?