# Spring 4.2's native Global CORS support won't work with CAS filterProcessesUrl

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, cors, spring-security-cas

i am trying to switch to spring 4.2's native Global CORS support after i upgrade to spring-boot 1.3, but it seemed won't work with CAS filter process url(/login/cas).

Originally, i was using spring-boot 1.2.7 with spring 4.2 and spring-security 4.0.2, and using self made filtered based cors support. And either my own rest service or CAS ST validation URL worked well. After i upgraded to spring-boot 1.3 with coming in spring and spring-security version. It stopped working. 
After some digging, fixed this by [AddFilterBefore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886186/how-to-setup-access-control-allow-origin-filter-problematically-in-spring-securi). So filtered based CORS seemed work well too with spring-boot 1.3.0 +  spring-security-cas.

However, i want to use native Global CORS, but it seemed the CAS ST validation URL(/login/cas) can't be recognized, though other rest endpoints are OK.

Please help.

The setup is quite straight forward.

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

                registry.addMapping("/**");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And following are some trafic:

```
    Request URL:http://localhost:9000/login/cas?ticket=ST-1357-15aQrv93jGEUsQpQRF1P-cas01.example.org
    Request Method:GET
    Status Code:302 Found

    Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Content-Length:0
    Date:Thu, 19 Nov 2015 09:19:31 GMT
    Expires:0
    Location:http://localhost:9000/
    Pragma:no-cache
    Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
    X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
    X-Frame-Options:DENY
    X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

and following are console errors:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/login/cas?ticket=ST-1357-15aQrv93jGEUsQpQRF1P-cas01.example.org. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CORS native support is done by default at Spring MVC `HandlerMapping` level, so it is expected that your CAS filter will not be CORS enabled, since it handles request earlier.

One option to consider is using the `org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter` we also provide with Spring Framework 4.2 with the `AddFilterBefore` approach.

Be aware that `CorsConfiguration` has not the same default configuration than `@CrossOrigin` or `CorsRegistry`, so you need to define most of the properties yourself, for example:

```
UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true); // you USUALLY want this
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    CorsFilter filter = new CorsFilter(source);
    // ...
```

Comment: thanks.  i am not sure if i got it right.  **CORS native support is done by default at Spring MVC HandlerMapping level** , since CAS filterProcessesUrl(/login/cas) is not in handler mappings(we can verify this by checking Actuator endpoint: /mappings), so CORS native support will not work for it?

Comment: Spring CORS support is available and enabled by default at `HandlerMapping` level, but is also available as an alternative at filter level  thanks to `org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter`. When you are using the filter, `HandlerMapping` level processing [is automatically disabled if the response already contains CORS headers](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/cors/DefaultCorsProcessor.java#L75). In your use case, you probably just want to configure and rely on `CorsFilter`.